# Check if any of the values in my array = 15, then do something

Tags: php, arrays, counting

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [10:00:00] => 15
    [10:30:00] => 15
    [11:00:00] => 8
)
```

I need to see if any of them equal 15, if so do something.
There will be more items being added in the future. The items are all time slots and the number on the right is the amount of bookings. No more than 15 bookings per time slot.

The times will go into a form as select options. I either need to show all and disable the fully booked ones, or only show the available slots.

The other way it could be done is by looking for all the ones that don't equal 15 and then adding them to the select.

I will of course include some server side validation to stop more than 15 being allocated to a time slot.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way of doing it ...

```php
if (in_array(15, $myArray)) {
  // Do something
}
```

... as @AbraCadaver mentioned, it is from the official PHP manual at https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Just curious where does in_array comes from?

Comment: @JamM.HernandezQ. It's a built in PHP function

Comment: Guys, if you downvote, at least take the time to leave a comment.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there is little context in your answer. Nothing that describes what the code does

Comment: Holy cow. The code does what was originally asked. And it is literally a super simple statement that has a link to the PHP documentation that thoroughly explains the in_array() function. Unless it was mentioned in the original question, this is not a PHP 101 class where I am thought I should explain what an if() statement does with the in_array() when the like to the source of that data was provided.

Answer (score 2):

To get an array of all of those NOT equal to 15:

```
$result = array_filter(function($v) { return $v != 15; }, $array);
```

To check if a value is in an array you can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php), however for your use case you are looking to eliminate ALL of the 15 values from your select.  So just build an array of what you want.

[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5159168/andreas)'s comment didn't occur to me at first but is how I would normally do it:

```
$result = array_diff($array, [15]);
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer considering "_The other way it could be done is by looking for all the ones that don't equal 15 and then adding them to the select._".

Comment: yes I saw in_array but i couldn't work out how to use it in my situation. I am going to try this quickly and will mark correct if it works. thank you

Comment: I cant seem to get it to output anything. I replaced $array with the array, do i need to replace $v with something?

Comment: No, what is your array called?

Comment: $takenSlotsCount

Comment: here is what generates and displays it, i was putting your code below. 
      $takenSlotsCount = array_count_values($takenSlots);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($takenSlotsCount);
echo '</pre>';

$result = array_filter(function($v) { return $v != 15; }, $array);
echo $result;

Comment: I think array_diff is probably easier to use. `$result = array_diff($takenSlotsCount, [15]);`

Comment: $result is an array, you can't echo arrays.

Comment: Yeah i know i tried print_r it and nothing, even echo should output 'array'. array_diff worked like a charm thank you

Comment: Damn dude `$result = array_filter(function($v) { return $v != 15; }, $takenSlots);`

Comment: Don't mix it with other answers, just replace `$array` with your actual array name then use `$result`.

Comment: @CarlPiper There is nothing wrong with AbraCadavers answer. You just used the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) along with [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php).

```
if(isset(array_count_values($myArray)[15])) {
    //do something
}
```

Basically, `array_count_values()` will return an array, which, with your example would be:

```
[15 => 2, 8 => 1]
```

Which is just how many times each value appeared in the original array. Then we use `isset()` to check if the key `15` exists in the output from `array_count_values()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different build in methods in php to solve this.

some of them are.

1. [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
2. [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
3. [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
4. [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)
5. [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)
6. [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

here is how you do on them

1. `in_array`

   `if (in_array(15, $array)) // do your stuff here`
2. `array_search`

   `if (array_search(15, $array) !== false) // do your stuff here`
3. `array_filter`

   `if (! empty(array_filter($array, function ($a) { return $a == 15; })) // do your stuff here`
4. `array_reduce`

   `if (array_reduce($array, function ($c, $d) { return $c = $c == 15 || $d == 15 ? 15 : 0; }) -- 15) // do your stuff here`
5. `array_diff`

   `if (count(array_diff($array, [ 15 ])) != count($array)) // do your stuff here`
6. `array_intersect`

   `if (! empty(array_intersect($array, [15]))) // do your stuff here`

There are many more methods, depending on the logic you use.

Comment: This looks more like a list of ideas on how to solve the problem - but doesn't actually contain anything which answers the original question.

Comment: I could see many solutions for the answer here. So just wanted to stop that by providing all the possibilities. The logic on how to use them has to be applied by the developer.

Comment: I am not sure of who made that down vote. but please explain the reason for that.

Comment: Some people are just going around and sending the wrong message by being trigger happy with the down-vote button. I personally like this solution so I will up-vote it.

Comment: Thank you, I too agree to what you stated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to show a `select` box, you will need to iterate over the array anyway. The only senseful condition before doing so could be whether or not already *all* slots are booked. Then you might not want to show the `<select>` at all but some notice instead. Looking if *at least one* is `15` does *not* seem to make sense.

`count($slots) === (array_count_values($slots)[15]??0)` is true when all slots are booked.

The complete code generating enabled/disabled `<options>` or no `<select>` box at all could look like:

```
$slots =
[
  '10:00:00' => 15,
  '10:30:00' => 15,
  '11:00:00' => 8,
];

if(count($slots) === (array_count_values($slots)[15]??0))
{
?>
<div>No slots are available anymore.</div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>

<select name="slot">
  <option value="">select a time slot</option>
<?php
  foreach ($slots as $k=>$v)
  {
    $avail = 15-intval($v);
?>
  <option value="<?php echo $k;?>"<?php if($avail < 1) echo ' disabled'?>><?php echo "$k ($avail available)";?></option>
<?php
  }
?>
</select>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that this is amazing, it fails on the question marks tho in the array_count_values($slots)[15]??0

Comment: @CarlPiper `??` is the null coalescing operator of PHP7 http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php All versions below 7.1 are not supported anymore. You should upgrade your PHP to a recent version. The alternative in PHP<7 is `isset(array_count_values($slots)[15] && count($slots) === array_count_values($slots)[15]`. That's just to suppress warnings on accessing unset array fields.

Comment: Thank you and I know it's for a client. I have recommended